# How to find child element using variable selector within parent built with incrementing variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

Trying to add an incrementing class name to an element (rows in an ajax cart), while doing the same to one of it's child elements (images within each cart row).

After the items are numbered, show the matching image that has the same number in class name.

ex. cartitem-1 shows cartimage-1

```
var itemCount=0;
var imgCartCount=0;

if ($('.ajax-cart-row').length) {
  // itemize cart rows
  $('.ajax-cart-row').each(function() {
    itemCount++;
    var cartItemNumber = 'cartitem-'+itemCount;
    $(this).addClass(cartItemNumber);
    $(this).val(itemCount);
    console.log('cart numbers loaded');
  });
  // itemize images in cart
  $('.ajax-cart-row img').each(function() {
    IMGCount++;
    var cartImgs = 'cartimg-'+IMGCount;
    $(this).addClass(cartImgs);
    $(this).val(IMGCount);

    $(this).closest('.ajax-cart-row').find('[class*='+cartImgs+']').show();
    console.log('image numbers added');
  });

}
```

edit: There are multiple cartitem-# img elements without any individual classes/ids/filenames to go by. That's what this is for hopefully.

Hopefully I'm not just sleep deprived here... Thanks in advance

Comment: IMGCount variable is not declared and initialised, rather you have declare & initialised imgCartCount but never used it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what you're going for, or what is wrong with your code (except that "show" simply ensures that the element is not hidden - maybe your images are hidden by default?). See if something like this makes any difference:

```js
var itemCount=0;

if ($('.ajax-cart-row').length) {
  // itemize cart rows
  $('.ajax-cart-row').each(function() {
    itemCount++;
    var cartItemNumber = 'cartitem-'+itemCount;
    var cartRow = $(this);
    cartRow.addClass(cartItemNumber);
    cartRow.val(itemCount);
    console.log('cart numbers loaded');
    
    // add class to the image subelements (assumes only one, or that the same class is added to all img children of cartitem-#)
    var imageIdx = 0;
    cartRow.find("img").each(function() {
      imageIdx++;
      var cartImgs = 'cartimg-'+imageIdx;
      var cartImg = $(this);
      cartImg.addClass(cartImgs);
      cartImg.val(itemCount);
      
      if (imageIdx === itemCount) {
         cartImg.show();
      }
      console.log('image numbers added');
    });
  });

}
```

This should ensure that all img children of an itemized .ajax-cart-row will receive the same index in the class name as the row received (i.e. all img tags within cartitem-1 will receive a the cartimg-1 class). I hope that is what you are looking for.

Comment: You're right images are hidden by display:none. There are multiple child images inside each cartitem-#. Your code works, but gives each cartitem-# img child the same cartimg-# class. Thanks I'm much closer now but still struggling.

Comment: Based on your question, I assumed that you wanted all of the images within a single row to have the same index associated. Does it really matter if the images have an index that matches the row they're in, or can they have any kind of cartimg-# index?

Comment: In order to best help, we would need to know exactly what kind of result you are expecting. Do you want the image indexes to start over for each row (like this: cartitem-1 -> cartimg-1, cartimg-2, cartimg-3; cartitem-2 -> cartimg-1, cartimg-2, cartimg-3 ...)? Do you want all of the images, regardless of their row, to have incremental classes (like this: cartitem-1 -> cartimg-1, cartimg-2, cartimg-3; cartitem-2 -> cartimg-4, cartimg-5, cartimg-6 ...)?

Comment: Thanks. Great question. The only reason they have the matching row # is to ensure the corresponding image is shown. 3+ rows, 3+ hidden images per row > row 3 shows image 3.

Comment: Do all the rows contain the same exact images, just calling "show" on the image index that corresponds to the row index?

Comment: I updated the answer slightly. Does it get closer to what you're looking for?

Comment: That's correct. They show the same images (nothing I can do about that atm).

Comment: In that case, the updated code snippet in my answer should be what your looking for.

Comment: Brilliant. Never would have thought to === both variables against each other like that. Answer marked.